# std::from_chars overload for wchar_t?

Tags: c++, string, wchar-t, c++23

Is there any reason why [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) doesn't have an overload for `wchar_t`?

Currently, there are only four overloads one of them being:

```
constexpr std::from_chars_result from_chars( const char* first, const char* last,
                                             /*see below*/& value, int base = 10 );
```

So what is the reason that there doesn't exist any overload for `wchar_t` or other character types? Is there any chance that they will be added in C++26? If not then are there equivalents for `wchar_t`?

Comment: `wchar_t` is a bit of a mess. Its size isn't fixed, and Crom only knows what encoding the data in it uses. With that much unknown I wouldn't want to specify or try to implement a `wchar_t` overload either. That leads to Snark answer: Because then it would be `std::from_wchars`?

Comment: @user4581301 `std::from_wchars` is a better name. I guess it would be handy if we had it in the std library.

Comment: I knew I shouldn't have gotten snarky. It distracts from the real point: `wchar_t` is the Wild West. There are too many unknowns to be able to specify how `from_chars` would have to behave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `from/to_chars` series of functions are for [elementary string conversions](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0067r0.html). These are the most elemental of numeric conversions. As such, they only support the most basic encoding: your system's native narrow character set (usually Unicode codepoints less than 128 encoded as UTF-8 or ASCII).

If you have text in some other encoding, it is on yourself to convert that encoding from/to the system narrow encoding in order to use these functions.

The expected use cases for these strings are for things like writing to/reading from textual formats like JSON. Such files are almost universally UTF-8 encoded (or ASCII), and when they call for numbers, their numbers are both locale-independent (always using `.` for the radix mark, for example) and encodes numbers using only the ASCII-part of Unicode.

Comment: So I guess there is no hope for the `wchar_t` versions.